# Unable to read configmap in spring boot app using cloud kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I'm trying to setup spring boot application with cloud kubernetes to read configmap with the following configuration.

Pod service account:

```
serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
```

Role:

```
Name:         configmap-reader
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources   Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------   -----------------  --------------  -----
  configmaps  []                 []              [get list watch]
  endpoints   []                 []              [get list watch]
  pods        []                 []              [get list watch]
  secrets     []                 []              [get list watch]
  services    []                 []              [get list watch]
```

RoleBinding:

```
Name:         configmap-default-binding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  configmap-reader
Subjects:
  Kind            Name     Namespace
  ----            ----     ---------
  ServiceAccount  default  app-nonprod
```

Spring boot & cloud version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configuration in app.properties

```
spring.application.name=sample

spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources.namespace=app-nonprod
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources.name=sample-configmap
spring.config.import=kubernetes:
```

configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "sample-configmap"
  labels:
    spring-config: "true"
data:
  application.yml: |-
    server:
      shutdown: graceful
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: {{ .Values.app.environment }}
    management:
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: "health,info"
    value: "Value from configmap"
```

When I start the application, I get this error:

```
2023-06-13T17:22:39.928Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.c.k.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils  : Failed to get pod with name:[]. You should look into this if things aren't working as you expect. Are you missing serviceaccount permissions?

io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:888) ~[client-java-api-17.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:50898) ~[client-java-api-17.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:50874) ~[client-java-api-17.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:87) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.LazilyInstantiate.get(LazilyInstantiate.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.getDetails(KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:94) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:47) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:80) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:321) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:428) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:738) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.kt:128) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.kt:295) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:207) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:226) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.kubernetes.client.util.credentials.TokenFileAuthentication.intercept(TokenFileAuthentication.java:72) ~[client-java-17.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154) ~[okhttp-4.10.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:884) ~[client-java-api-17.0.2.jar!/:na]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Is there something I missed in the configuration/service account/role/rolebinding?
I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the block:

```
spec:
  hostname: "..."
```

if you have some in your yaml templates.

Because spring cloud kubernetes will try to find a pod with that name.